# Java Lazy Load Singleton in Abstract Class

Tags: java, singleton, lazy-loading

I am trying to achieve Singleton Instance with Abstract class in Java. I have read like implementing it as a LazyLoad is the best practice. I could not make it as I am not much used to this pattern and even Java.

1. getInstance() is always null, I am not sure why?
2. I don't think this follows lazy loading as the instance is constructed.
3. Any additional comments are welcome apart from this as I am completely new to Java and worked on c# before.

Here is what I have,

**Interface:**

```
public interface IConditionAppender{
    public String Append();
}
```

**Abstract**

```
public abstract AppenderBase {

    private static IConditionAppender instance;

    protected AppenderBase(IConditionAppender instance)
    {
         this.instance = instance;
    }

    public static IConditionAppender getInstance(){ return instance; }
}
```

**Implementation**

```
public final class AndAppender extends AppenderBase implements IConditionAppender {

private AndAppender()
{
    super(new AndAppender())
}

@Override
public String Append()
{
    return " AND ";
}
```

}

**Test**

```
System.out.println(AndAppender.getInstance().Append());
```

Comment: Where are you calling parametrized constructor of `AppenderBase` ?

Comment: @AshishkumarSingh, Sorry missed new keyword and it is constructed in AndAppender class

Comment: why is your AndAppender class constructor private?

Comment: With this design you cannot create `OrAppender` as the `instance` static field in `AppenderBase` will be replaced

Comment: @tuktuk, I am not sure, just referred some singleton instance and did the same

Comment: @Maxim, Yes just noticed, any suggestions on this please?

Comment: Don't implement Singleton through inheritance as it uses static field and method which are not involved in late binding. You should implement Singleton for each And/OrOperation class

Comment: For lazy initialization you can use, Suppliers from https://github.com/google/guava
It will be looking like `this.instance = Suppliers.memoize (x->new Instance())`
And get instance with `this.instance.get()`. Or you can use `CompletableFeature`s from java.util.concurrency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how `AndAppender` can be implemented

```
public final class AndAppender implements ConditionAppender {
    private static final AndAppender instance;
    public static AndAppender getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new AndAppender();
        return instance;
    }

    private AndAppender() { }

    @Override
    public String append() {
        return " AND ";
    }
}
```

The same approach for `OrAppender` etc.

**Note:** this implementation is not thread-safe.

---

A bit simpler way is to use `Enum` which is singleton by default and can implement interfaces.

```
public enum  Appender implements ConditionAppender {
    AND(" AND "), OR(" OR ");

    final String operation;

    Appender(String operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    @Override
    public String append() {
        return operation;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(AND.append());
        System.out.println(OR.append());

    }
}
```

Comment: `private static final AndAppender instance = new AndAppender()` works same right?

Comment: No. It's not **lazy**, an instance of `AndAppender` will be created at class loading time, not at first time it requested with `getInstance()` method

Answer (score 1):

The code below may help you~

```
public abstract class AbstractSingleton {

    private static Map<String, AbstractSingleton> registryMap = new HashMap<String, AbstractSingleton>();

    AbstractSingleton() throws SingletonException {
        String clazzName = this.getClass().getName();
        if (registryMap.containsKey(clazzName)) {
            throw new SingletonException("Cannot construct instance for class " + clazzName + ", since an instance already exists!");
        } else {
            synchronized (registryMap) {
                if (registryMap.containsKey(clazzName)) {
                    throw new SingletonException("Cannot construct instance for class " + clazzName + ", since an instance already exists!");
                } else {
                    registryMap.put(clazzName, this);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends AbstractSingleton> T getInstance(final Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        String clazzName = clazz.getName();
        if (!registryMap.containsKey(clazzName)) {
            synchronized (registryMap) {
                if (!registryMap.containsKey(clazzName)) {
                    T instance = clazz.newInstance();
                    return instance;
                }
            }
        }
        return (T) registryMap.get(clazzName);
    }

    public static AbstractSingleton getInstance(final String clazzName)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        if (!registryMap.containsKey(clazzName)) {
            Class<? extends AbstractSingleton> clazz = Class.forName(clazzName).asSubclass(AbstractSingleton.class);
            synchronized (registryMap) {
                if (!registryMap.containsKey(clazzName)) {
                    AbstractSingleton instance = clazz.newInstance();
                    return instance;
                }
            }
        }
        return registryMap.get(clazzName);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends AbstractSingleton> T getInstance(final Class<T> clazz, Class<?>[] parameterTypes, Object[] initargs)
            throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException,
            InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        String clazzName = clazz.getName();
        if (!registryMap.containsKey(clazzName)) {
            synchronized (registryMap) {
                if (!registryMap.containsKey(clazzName)) {
                    Constructor<T> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(parameterTypes);
                    T instance = constructor.newInstance(initargs);
                    return instance;
                }
            }
        }
        return (T) registryMap.get(clazzName);
    }

    static class SingletonException extends Exception {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8633183690442262445L;

        private SingletonException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
}
```

From: https://www.cnblogs.com/wang9192/p/3975748.html